# How to decrypt the hashed password in php ? password hashed with password_hash() method

Tags: php, encryption, password-hash

I want to decrypt the encrypted password that is encrypted by php's password_hash() method.

```
<?php

    $password = 12345;
    $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

?>
```

in above code i want to decrypt `$hashed_password` to `12345`. how can i do it.

Comment: You can't. That's the whole point of encrypting passwords.

Comment: You are mixing encryption with hashing. The hash function is one way. You cannot decrypt it, unless a weak hash function was used, then you might find a collision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to

> The used algorithm, cost and salt are returned as part of the hash.
>   Therefore, all information that's needed to verify the hash is
>   included in it. This allows the password_verify() function to verify
>   the hash without needing separate storage for the salt or algorithm
>   information.

```
    $passwordEnteredFirstTime = '12345';
    $passwordEnteredSecondTime = '12345';

    $passwordHash = password_hash($passwordEnteredFirstTime, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $passIsValid = password_verify($passwordEnteredSecondTime, $passwordHash);
    echo $passIsValid ? 'correct password' : 'wrong password';
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

> password_hash() creates a new password hash using a strong *one-way* hashing algorithm.

From [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).